# Shortening build command

Tags: gcc, command, g++, pkg-config

Is there any way I can shorten this openCV build command?

```
g++ file.cpp -o newFileName `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv`
```

I tried adding:

```
-o newFileName `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv`
```

to an alias but it just keep returning command not found, is there any other way to shorten this command?

EDIT:

As per suggestions below I have created a `makefile` with the following content:

```
OPENCV='pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv'
%: %.cpp
    $(CXX) -o $* $*.cpp $(OPENCV)
```

but when I run `make surfPoints` I am getting the following output (the file builds fine when the command is manually ran):

```
$ make surfPoints
g++ -o surfPoints surfPoints.cpp 
/tmp/ccxxAU92.o: In function `main':
surfPoints.cpp:(.text+0x81): undefined reference to `cv::imread(std::string const&, int)'
surfPoints.cpp:(.text+0xf3): undefined reference to `cv::imread(std::string const&, int)'
surfPoints.cpp:(.text+0x17f): undefined reference to `cv::SURF::SURF(double, int, int, bool, bool)'
surfPoints.cpp:(.text+0x1d0): undefined reference to `cv::FeatureDetector::detect(cv::Mat const&, std::vector<cv::KeyPoint, std::allocator<cv::KeyPoint> >&, cv::Mat const&) const'
surfPoints.cpp:(.text+0x212): undefined reference to `cv::FeatureDetector::detect(cv::Mat const&, std::vector<cv::KeyPoint, std::allocator<cv::KeyPoint> >&, cv::Mat const&) const'
surfPoints.cpp:(.text+0x280): undefined reference to `cv::drawKeypoints(cv::Mat const&, std::vector<cv::KeyPoint, std::allocator<cv::KeyPoint> > const&, cv::Mat&, cv::Scalar_<double> const&, int)'
surfPoints.cpp:(.text+0x2c1): undefined reference to `cv::drawKeypoints(cv::Mat const&, std::vector<cv::KeyPoint, std::allocator<cv::KeyPoint> > const&, cv::Mat&, cv::Scalar_<double> const&, int)'
surfPoints.cpp:(.text+0x2d7): undefined reference to `cv::_InputArray::_InputArray(cv::Mat const&)'
surfPoints.cpp:(.text+0x30b): undefined reference to `cv::imshow(std::string const&, cv::_InputArray const&)'
surfPoints.cpp:(.text+0x339): undefined reference to `cv::_InputArray::_InputArray(cv::Mat const&)'
surfPoints.cpp:(.text+0x36d): undefined reference to `cv::imshow(std::string const&, cv::_InputArray const&)'
surfPoints.cpp:(.text+0x38f): undefined reference to `cv::waitKey(int)'
/tmp/ccxxAU92.o: In function `cv::Mat::~Mat()':
surfPoints.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv3MatD2Ev[_ZN2cv3MatD5Ev]+0x39): undefined reference to `cv::fastFree(void*)'
/tmp/ccxxAU92.o: In function `cv::Mat::release()':
surfPoints.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv3Mat7releaseEv[_ZN2cv3Mat7releaseEv]+0x47): undefined reference to `cv::Mat::deallocate()'
/tmp/ccxxAU92.o: In function `cv::Feature2D::~Feature2D()':
surfPoints.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv9Feature2DD2Ev[_ZN2cv9Feature2DD2Ev]+0x69): undefined reference to `cv::DescriptorExtractor::~DescriptorExtractor()'
surfPoints.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv9Feature2DD2Ev[_ZN2cv9Feature2DD2Ev]+0x80): undefined reference to `cv::FeatureDetector::~FeatureDetector()'
surfPoints.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv9Feature2DD2Ev[_ZN2cv9Feature2DD2Ev]+0x98): undefined reference to `cv::Algorithm::~Algorithm()'
surfPoints.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv9Feature2DD2Ev[_ZN2cv9Feature2DD2Ev]+0xcc): undefined reference to `cv::FeatureDetector::~FeatureDetector()'
surfPoints.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv9Feature2DD2Ev[_ZN2cv9Feature2DD2Ev]+0xe9): undefined reference to `cv::Algorithm::~Algorithm()'
/tmp/ccxxAU92.o: In function `cv::SURF::~SURF()':
surfPoints.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv4SURFD1Ev[_ZN2cv4SURFD1Ev]+0xe): undefined reference to `vtable for cv::SURF'
surfPoints.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv4SURFD1Ev[_ZN2cv4SURFD1Ev]+0x26): undefined reference to `vtable for cv::SURF'
surfPoints.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv4SURFD1Ev[_ZN2cv4SURFD1Ev]+0x2e): undefined reference to `vtable for cv::SURF'
surfPoints.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv4SURFD1Ev[_ZN2cv4SURFD1Ev]+0x3b): undefined reference to `VTT for cv::SURF'
surfPoints.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv4SURFD1Ev[_ZN2cv4SURFD1Ev]+0x62): undefined reference to `cv::Algorithm::~Algorithm()'
surfPoints.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv4SURFD1Ev[_ZN2cv4SURFD1Ev]+0x97): undefined reference to `cv::Algorithm::~Algorithm()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [surfPoints] Error 1
```

Comment: you would usually use a Makefile as I describe here: http://www.linuxintro.org/wiki/Makefile. Then you could just run the command make.

Comment: I personally prefer scons, but make would work as well. Typing a command manually every time is definitely a very bad idea and a waste of time.

Comment: @FaheemMitha, and a source of mysterious problems later on, when along the line a compilation is skipped or given the wrong flags.

Comment: @vonbrand I've never had mysterious problems with scons. The worst thing people say about it, is that it is too slow. And that is only an issue with large build projects; like thousands of files.

Comment: @FOLKS - the guy is asking about a single command w/ alias. It's good to make suggestions but let's not hijack his Q with suppositions about what he may or may not be doing. Let the OP ask the questions!!!

Comment: @slm : I think it's fine to explain how to do this with an alias since that's what the OP is trying to do, but in the context of building and compiling, using `alias` is really a "canonically wrong" answer. It's not as if we are chiming in with "how to do this in python", etc.  Using a make/build system is *the most correct way* to shorten a build command. By analogy, if someone asks, "How do I hammer in this screw?", an answer explaining how to most easily hammer in a screw is not wrong, but a better answer would be "If the goal is getting the screw in, you are best off not using a hammer..."

Comment: @goldilocks - my comment was directed to the commenters here, I have no issues with the A's suggesting to use a build tool. I've amended my A to touch on that particular point as well.

Comment: @goldilocks, I try to *solve* OP's problems, not just answer their questions. They might have painted themselves into a corner.

Comment: @FaheemMitha, no issue with scons. Just pointing out that typing in complex compilation commands is error-prone.

Comment: @vonbrand : I think we're on the same page with that.

Answer (score 3):

[`make`](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html) is the tool you need. You just need to type `make` with the `Makefile` in place and your file will be build.

Here is a simple Makefile that would generate the file `newFileName` according to the line you posted in the question:

```
MYFLAGS=$(shell pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv)

newFileName: file.cpp
    $(CXX) $< -o $@ $(MYFLAGS)
```

If you place this in your code directory, simply type `make` and your code will be build.

Brief explanation:

- `make` will look for the Makefile in the directory;
- Because the file is there, `make` will execute first rule: newFileName, and execute it;
- This rule syntax is the following:

  - `newFileName:` sets the name of the rule, or target, preferably the name of the file that the rule will roduce;
  - Everything after the `:` are prerequisites, in other words files that will be necessary for the execution of the recipe of this rule or rules that should be executed before;
  - The line(s) bellow are the recipe (notice the  or 4 spaces in the beginning of the line), they tell make how to produce the file `newFileName`.
- `$(CXX)` will expand to your default C++ compiler and `MYFLAGS` will expand to the output of `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv`.

**Bonus:** Make will execute the recipe of a rule only if the prerequisites were changed after the creation time-stamp of the target, so if you type `make` and you already have a up to date newFileName file, you wont lost time recompiling something that you already have. This is specially nice when you have lots of files.

Answer (score 3):

The sooner you learn to use `make` the better.  Create a `makefile` in the same directory as `file.cpp` -- beware **make requires use of an actual <kbd>tab</kbd> to indent.**  If you use spaces, you'll get a "missing separator" error:

```
OPENCV=`pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv`

newFileName: file.cpp
    $(CXX) -o newFileName file.cpp $(OPENCV)
```

To build, just run `make` in that directory.  This will check the [rule for the first *target*](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Rule-Introduction) in the makefile.  In this case, there's only one, the `newFileName` target.  Since `file.cpp` is a *prerequisite*, if a file with the target name doesn't exist, or it exists but the modification time of the prerequisite is newer (i.e., you modified `file.cpp` since `newFileName` was last built), the *recipe* will be executed.

To make sure `$(CXX)` is defined on your system, run `make -p | grep CXX` **in a directory with NO makefile**.   The output should include `CXX = g++`.

---

If you add another target, e.g.:

```
otherFile: file2.cpp
    $(CXX) -o otherFile file2.cpp $(OPENCV)
```

You can execute this rule by using the target name, `make otherFile`.  Again, if no target is given, the first one in the makefile is used.

Since those two targets follow an identical pattern, if you used executable names that matched source file names, you could do this:

```
%: %.cpp
    $(CXX) -o $* $*.cpp $(OPENCV)
```

Now, `make whatever` will run

```
g++ -o whatever whatever.cpp `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv`
```

See [How Patterns Match](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Pattern-Match) and [Automatic Variables](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Automatic-Variables) for an explanation of how this works.

---

Make becomes especially useful as you start doing more complex things -- compiling object (`.o`) files and combining them into executables, etc.  Eventually, *you will have to learn* to use some kind of build system, and `make` is most common one in the *nix world.

Comment: When I try to run the command `make SURF_detector surfPoints.cpp` it is giving the message:
`make: *** No rule to make target `SURF_detector'.  Stop.`

My makeFile:
`%: %.cpp
    $(CXX) -o $* $*.cpp $(OPENCV)`

Comment: Because if you use that rule you must also use executable names that correspond to the name of the source file.  So `make surfPoints` would compile `surfPoints.cpp` into an executable `surfPoints`.  You can't fill in the prereq on the commandline -- each arg will be taken as a target -- so if there is no `SURF_detector.cpp` that command will fail that way.  If you want use arbitrary executable names that don't match the source file name, you'll have to use a specific custom rule as per the first example.

Comment: Ahh OK, I'm having another problem when I run `make surfPoints`, it is producing a long list of errors but I am able to compile the file myself if I manually type the command in. I'll update my question so it's readable.

Comment: Hmmm. `OPENCV='pkg-config foobar --cflags --libs'` (where `'` is a actually a backtick) works for me with other pkg-config stuff, but you could try RSFalcon7's suggested `OPENCV=$(shell pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv)`.

Answer (score 2):

You have 3 options for shortening things within a typical  shell such as Bash.

1. Make a shell script
2. Make an alias
3. Make a function

I'll show you 2 & 3.

#### alias

You could do something like this as an alias.

```
$ alias mygcc='g++ file.cpp -o newFileName $(pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv)'
```

The biggest limitation with an alias is that you can't really pass it a list of arguments. Think of an alias as a macro that will explode into a longer string, but that string is effectively fixed, you can't substitute values in to different spots within the string.

You can finagle it a bit by strategically positioning a filename or other arguments so that they occur at the end of the alias.

```
$ alias myalias='ls -l'

$ myalias -d
drwxrwxr-x. 2 saml saml 4096 Jan 24 11:19 .

$ myalias file1
-rw-rw-r--. 1 saml saml 0 Jan 24 11:19 file1
```

So when we run `myalias` we can give it filenames or other switches and it works.

#### function

Functions can do a whole lot more. You can put things in here like error checking or run some other command and store its results in a variable. So making this a function would allow you manipulate arguments within the string.

```
$ mygcc () { g++ file.cpp -o newFileName $(pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv); }
```

#### Going beyond?

If you need more than just a simple one-liner then I'd urge you to look into using a proper tool such as Make, CMake, or any one of the myriad of dependency building tools.

- [Build automation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Build_automation)
- [List of build automation software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_build_automation_software)

The selection of a build tool should be a discussion that you and your team has though, don't just go off and pick something. The choice should be made so that an appropriate tool for your team & technologies that you're using to build your application(s).

Comment: Please don't. Use the tool for the job, i.e., some dependency-based build machinery.

Comment: @vonbrand - re-read my A: "You have 3 options for shortening things within a typical shell such as Bash". I was only addressing his Q about how one would shorten a single command. I wasn't getting a soapbox about Make, Cmake, etc.etc. There are any number of tools he could use here but that wasn't what he was asking for!

Comment: I did read it. And you answer the question, but give non-solutions to the "build a package reliably" problem.

Comment: @vonbrand - fair enough, I've since added a section on build tools.